# Capitalize first letters of each word in text input

Tags: php, html

I have a database that stores the input from this current text input:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" required>
```

Is it somehow possible to capitalize the first letter in each work, so if the user write `James bond` or `james bond` the output will be `James Bond`?

I know about `style="text-transform: capitalize;"` but as I understand, this only change the letters that are displayed, but the actual data in form data will still be as the user entered it.

Comment: in php you can use `ucwords`

Comment: Keep in mind that names are more complex than camel case. Generally I don't like when a system makes changes or has "opinions" about what I type. There are people with names that is not "standard", respect them too. There are names from other cultures that make me giggle due to what they mean in my language and we have a female name in our language that is "Fanny". And they generally have problems with English speaking forms due to developers adding opinions in the code.

Comment: @Andreas how do you think X Æ A-12 will feel when he grows up.

Comment: @NigelRen I had to Google that. So... Are they leading the weird names challenge?

Answer (score 0):

ucwords() is what you're looking for.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo ucwords($fullname); ?>" required>
```

Comment: Will have a look at this, thanks! Also may I ask, how can I accomplish only lowercase letters?

Comment: to get all lowercase you can do the transformation in either PHP ( `strtolower($word)` ) or in mySQL ( `lower("WORD")` )

Comment: @Kanu111 you know there are search engines that can help you with the very basic questions too.

Comment: @Andreas No sorry, I don't know.